# Javascript arrays giving NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a bit of HTML that is supposed to bounce ball(s) around the canvas, but the arrays storing the coordinates seem to be 'NaN' when I set them to a random position and test with `alert("Co-ordinates " + (cirX[i]) + " x " + (cirY[i]));`.  This returns 'Co-ordinates NaN x NaN'.  I have tried to do it with one ball without the arrays and it worked.  I am not sure if I am coding my arrays badly or if it is something else.  Here is my HTML:

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<head>
<script>
var cirX = [];
var cirY = [];
var chX = [];
var chY = [];
var width;
var height;

function initCircle(nBalls) {
  alert(nBalls)
  for(var i = 0; i<nBalls;i++) {
    alert("loop  " + i)
    chX[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random()*200)/10);
    chY[i] = (Math.floor(Math.random()*200)/10);
    cirX[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*width);
    cirY[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*height);
    alert("Co-ordinates " + (cirX[i]) + " x " + (cirY[i]));

    circle(cirX[i],cirY[i],3);
    setInterval('moveBall(i)',10);
  }
}

function moveBall(ballNum) {
    if(cirX[ballNum] > width||cirX[ballNum] < 0) {
      chX[ballNum] = 0-chX[ballNum];
    }
    if(cirY[ballNum] > height|| cirY[ballNum] < 0) {
      chY[ballNum] = 0-chY[ballNum];
    }
    cirX[ballNum] = cirX[ballNum] + chX[ballNum];
    cirY[ballNum] = cirY[ballNum] + chY[ballNum];
    circle(cirX[ballNum],cirY[ballNum],3);

}

function circle(x,y,r) {
  var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = canvas.width;
  ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.fill();
  width = canvas.width;
  height = canvas.height;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300">
</canvas>
<script>
initCircle(3); //this sets the number of circles
</script>
</body>
```

I have looked up how to initialise arrays e.c.t, but I seem to be doing it right? Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT:**
Despite fixing the above problems, only one ball moves and at varying speeds despite the variable `ballNum` in `moveBall()` varying from 0 to 2 as expected (tested by adding `alert(ballNum)`).  Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think the index is messed up, did you check the value of i, before retrieving cirX[i]?

Comment: No, I think the index is fine.  My problem was that width was not defined.  Also, `alert("loop  " + i)` checks i. @Stormherz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call this line

```
cirX[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*width);
```

when `width` is still undefined. So you can only get `NaN` as a result.

To properly call the `moveBall` function from setInterval, you may use

```
(function(i) { // embedds i to protect its value (so that it isn't the one of end of loop
   setInterval(function(){moveBall(i)}, 10);
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `width` is undefined when the statement gets executed for the first time. You can get the canvas and its dimension in the beginning and keep it global.

http://jsbin.com/agavoq/9/edit

To call setInterval you can use a self invoking function preserving the value of `i`

```
(function(x){
  setInterval(moveBall,10, x);
})(i);
```

Or simply

```
setInterval(moveBall,10, i);
```

Or

```
setInterval('moveBall(' + i+ ')',10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see another issue because look at this line

```
setInterval('moveBall(i)',10);
```

The `i` is not what you think it is. You should not use a string in `setTimeout`.