# Javascript 2D array returning NaN

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nan

I created a helper function to create 2D arrays but it always returns NaN values in Chrome.

```
var H = new Object();
H.N = 10;
H.M = 3;
function array2D(N,M,v){
    var temp = new Array(N);
        for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
            temp[i] = new Array(M);
            for(var j=0; j<M; j++){
                temp[i][j] = v;
            }
        }
     console.log(temp);
     return temp;
}
H.A = new array2D(H.N, H.M, 1/H.M);
```

When I print v, the correct value is given but the array still has the NaN values for each entry. I have looked at answers to these questions so far: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709801/array-of-array-returning-nan), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232812/javascript-arrays-giving-nan)  but nothing I change has worked. This is my first time working with Javascript; can someone explain my error?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/vnAgp/1/

Comment: I copypasted and ran the code as is and works fine

Comment: Ran on Chrome's developer tools and it creates the array and all...

Comment: I think calling the function with a constructor is weird, since it returns a value explicitly, but it seemed to work for me (which makes me worry about myself).

Comment: @Pointy if you return a non-primitive then that is returned instead of the created object

Comment: @Esailija yes, I know, but it's one of those things that my head randomly inverts so I never know which is which :)

Comment: Interesting, it works when I copy paste as well but not when I make the file in ssh and run online.